# Manually splitting and compressing input for Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, compression, hadoop-streaming, lzo

Instead of using `hadoop-lzo` to index my LZO input file, I decided to simply split it into a chunks, which compressed with LZO would be close to 128MB (since it is default block size on *Amazon Distribution*[[1]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HDFSConfig.html)).

Is there anything wrong (from cluster performance perspective) to provide input already split and compressed to a size close to a default HDFS block size?